# ODP.NET ExecuteReader Returns Zero Results When Rows Are Present

Tags: oracle, odp.net, oracle-manageddataaccess

When I execute the following code the value `dr.HasRows` is `false`, and `dr.Read()` returns false. The same query running in SQL Developer returns 10 rows:

```
var allTablesSql = "select * from all_tables where table_name = 'ADDFIELDSPIPES'";
var cmd = new OracleCommand(allTablesSql, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
if (dr.Read())
{
    // We have rows!
}
```

If I change my query to be as follows then `dr.HasRows` is `true` and `dr.Read()` returns `true`:

```
var allTablesSql = "select * from all_tables where table_name like '%'";
```

I suspect that ODP.NET somewhere and somehow queries metadata before executing the SQL string that I supply, and this metadata query somehow prevents ODP.NET from returning any rows for my query.

Comment: And `select * from ADDFIELDSPIPES` works also?

Comment: @CaiusJard When I execute that in SQL Developer I get rows, and I get rows when I use `OracleDataReader` as well

Comment: It seems to be a privileges issue. I had to up my user privileges to execute `select * from ADDFIELDSPIPES` and now, using that same user, my original query returns the expected 10 rows.

Comment: Seems reasonable that if you don;t have enough privs to select from a table you might also not be able to see it in an "all tables" list